# Ambigious redirect error on different volumes with mysql

Tags: bash, io-redirection, variable

i want to import a database with mysql (running with MAMP):

```
#! /bin/bash
# variables
currdir=$PWD
dbname=TEST
dbuser=root
dbpass=root
dbpath="/applications/MAMP/Library/bin"
exname=database

if [ "$1" = "import" ]
then
  cd $dbpath
  ./mysql -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname < $currdir/$exname.sql
fi
```

if my script and files are on a different volume as the mysql bin i get an

```
line 31: $currdir/$exname.sql: ambiguous redirect
```

error, if they are on the same volume the import works.
is it a permission error? echoing all variables give values, they are not empty, also first reading the file into a variable with

```
value=$(<$exname.sql)
```

does not work, though $value holds the contents of the file?
is it the cd? i tried to run mysql directly without the cd:

```
# cd $dbpath
/applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u (...)
```

but it also does not work.

Comment: Quoting variables [may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775870/10765659). You should quote them anyway.

Comment: You should quote the word following the redirection operator `<`, like this `"$currdir/$exname.sql"`. If it expands to more than one word, bash reports an error.

Comment: Quoting the variable expansions is the correct thing to do. However, not quoting them would in this case (with the values of the variables shown here) not be an issue.  Since the error message is indicating line 31 in a script, and you only show less than 15 lines, I'd be interested in seeing line 31...

Comment: Maybe his `$PWD` has a space character @Kusalananda

Comment: @StefanHamcke Ah. Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Variable expansions should be quoted to prevent

1. splitting of their values into separate words
2. filename globbing on the resulting words (less of an issue in your case, possibly).

If `$PWD` contains a space, and if the `IFS` variable has the default value (a space, tab and newline), then `$currdir/$exname.sql` would be split into at least two words.  This would then give rise to your "ambiguous redirect" error message in `bash`.

To resolve this, quote *all* variable expansions (especially `$dbpass` as passwords usually contains special characters):

```
if [ "$1" = "import" ]; then
  ( cd "$dbpath" &&
    ./mysql -u "$dbuser" -p"$dbpass" "$dbname" <"$currdir/$exname.sql" )
fi
```

Here, I have additionally done the `cd` and the `mysql` call in a subshell as to prevent the `cd` from changing the working directory for the rest of the script (although it's not clear why you actually need the `cd` in the first place).

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)